# Access Backbone fetch parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to be able to pass the server some info when calling fetch on a Backbone collection. On my front-end I have this code, passing data:{} to the fetch function along with the success and error callbacks. Looking at the docs for Backbone fetch:

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

perhaps I am not passing in the parameters correctly to the fetch function? Perhaps they should be in an array []...

```
var lineupCollection = new LineupCollection([]);
var loadTeamsOnPageLoad = (function() {

    lineupCollection.url = '/api/lineups';
    lineupCollection.fetch(
        {
            processData: true,
            data: {
            team_id:$("#team_id").attr("value")
        }
        },
        {
            success: function (result) {
                if(window.teamDashboardTableView === undefined){
                    window.teamDashboardTableView = new TeamDashboardTableView({el: $("#team-dashboard-table-div")});
                }
                window.teamDashboardTableView.render();
            },
            error: function (err) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    alert('error fetching lineupCollection - ' + err.message);
                }, 1);

            }
        }
    );
})();
```

which will load a Backbone collection into a table.

It's call this method on the back-end:

```
exports.getBackboneLineups = function(req,res,next){

    var user_id = req.mainUser._id;
    console.log('req.params',req.params); //empty {}
    console.log('req.team',req.team); //undefined
    console.log('team_id',req.team_id); //undefined
    console.log('req.data',req.data); //undefined
    console.log('req.body',req.body); //empty {}
    var team_id = req.team._id;  //undefined EXCEPTION, can't read property _id of undefined
    var system_db = req.system_db;
    var Lineup = LineupModel.getNewLineup(system_db,user_id);

    Lineup.find({team_id:team_id}, function (err, lineups) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.json(lineups);
    });

};
```

however, I am totally failing as far as how to access the data that I supposedly past to the server from the client. I can't really find a good example and I am getting tired of guessing. What's the best way to do this?

edit:
also tried passing `{data:{}, success: function(), error: function()}` all in the same JavaScript object, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` only takes one argument (see http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch). Instead, you should probably alter your backend to specify the team id in the resource's URL. For example:

```
lineupCollection.url = function(){ return '/api/lineups?team_id=' + this.team_id; };
lineupCollection.team_id = $("#team_id").attr("value");
lineupCollection.fetch({ success: ..., error: ...});
```

Comment: thanks, just to add, to access the ?params you have to use req.query in Node.js Express